# Align two trees in TiKZ (states/nodes)

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

In the following graph, i would like to align the tree with the states 11,12, 13, 14 such that 11-14 is a vertical chain, with state 11 being right of state 1, state 12 being right of state 3, state 13 being right of 6 and state 14 being right of state 10. How can I do this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta,positioning}

\newcommand{\iddots}{\reflectbox{$\ddots$}}
\begin{document}

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,-latex,shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=40mm,semithick, state/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=2cm}]
\node[state](1)                  {$S_0$};
\node[state](2)[below left  of=1] {$d\cdot S_0$};
\node[state](3)[below right of=1]{$u \cdot S_0$};
\node[state](4)[below left  of=2] {$d^2 \cdot S_0$};
\node[state](5)[below right of=2]{$du \cdot S_0$};
\node[state](6)[below right of=3]{$u^2 \cdot S_0$};
\node[state](7)[below left of=4]{$d^N \cdot S_0$};
\node[state](8)[below right of=4]{$d^k u^{N-k} \cdot S_0$};
\node[state](9)[below right of=5]{$d^{N-k}u^{k}\cdot S_0$};
\node[state](10)[below right of=6]{$u^N \cdot S_0$};
\node[state](14)[right of=10]{$S_1$};
\node[state](13)[above of=14, right of=6]{$S_1$};
\node[state](12)[above of=13, right of=3]{$S_1$};
\node[state](11)[above of=12, right of=1]{$S_1$};

\path (1) edge [swap] node {$1-p$}(2)
      (1) edge        node {$p$}(3)
      (2) edge [swap] node {$1-p$}(4)
      (2) edge        node {$p$}(5)
      (3) edge [swap] node {$1-p$}(5)
      (3) edge        node {$p$}(6);
       \node at ($(7)!.5!(8)$) {$\hdots$};
       \node at ($(8)!.5!(9)$) {$\hdots$};
       \node at ($(9)!.5!(10)$) {$\hdots$};
       
       \node at ($(4)!.5!(7)$) {\iddots};
       \node at ($(5)!.5!(8)$) {\iddots};
       \node at ($(6)!.5!(9)$) {\iddots};
       
       \node at ($(4)!.5!(8)$) {$\ddots$};
       \node at ($(5)!.5!(9)$) {$\ddots$};
       \node at ($(6)!.5!(10)$) {$\ddots$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

What I want (more or less):
[image: desired output]

Comment: Does changing `\node[state](13)[above of=14, right of=6]{$S_1$};` to `\node[state](13)[right of=6]{$S_1$};` solves your problem (also do this for 11 and 12)?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! But sadly no. Now, the chain is diagonal, but I would like to have a vertical chain.

Comment: Now I got it. So all the nodes should be vertical to 14?

Comment: For (13) you can remove the [right ...] and add `at (6-|14)`

Comment: Thanks, that solved it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like I mentioned in the comments, if you have two nodes, you can 'calculate' the corner of an imaginary rectangle using `-|` to place a node at this position. In your case, you have nodes (14) and (1), (3), (6), where you can align the other nodes at the desired positions.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta,positioning}

\newcommand{\iddots}{\reflectbox{$\ddots$}}
\begin{document}
    
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[->,-latex,shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=40mm,semithick, state/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=2cm}]
            \node[state](1)                  {$S_0$};
            \node[state](2)[below left  of=1] {$d\cdot S_0$};
            \node[state](3)[below right of=1]{$u \cdot S_0$};
            \node[state](4)[below left  of=2] {$d^2 \cdot S_0$};
            \node[state](5)[below right of=2]{$du \cdot S_0$};
            \node[state](6)[below right of=3]{$u^2 \cdot S_0$};
            \node[state](7)[below left of=4]{$d^N \cdot S_0$};
            \node[state](8)[below right of=4]{$d^k u^{N-k} \cdot S_0$};
            \node[state](9)[below right of=5]{$d^{N-k}u^{k}\cdot S_0$};
            \node[state](10)[below right of=6]{$u^N \cdot S_0$};
            \node[state](14)[right of=10]{$S_1$};
            \node[state](13) at (6-|14) {$S_1$};
            \node[state](12) at (3-|14) {$S_1$};
            \node[state](11) at (1-|14) {$S_1$};
            
            \path (1) edge [swap] node {$1-p$}(2)
            (1) edge        node {$p$}(3)
            (2) edge [swap] node {$1-p$}(4)
            (2) edge        node {$p$}(5)
            (3) edge [swap] node {$1-p$}(5)
            (3) edge        node {$p$}(6);
            \node at ($(7)!.5!(8)$) {$\hdots$};
            \node at ($(8)!.5!(9)$) {$\hdots$};
            \node at ($(9)!.5!(10)$) {$\hdots$};
            
            \node at ($(4)!.5!(7)$) {\iddots};
            \node at ($(5)!.5!(8)$) {\iddots};
            \node at ($(6)!.5!(9)$) {\iddots};
            
            \node at ($(4)!.5!(8)$) {$\ddots$};
            \node at ($(5)!.5!(9)$) {$\ddots$};
            \node at ($(6)!.5!(10)$) {$\ddots$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent use of `-|`. I hadn't thought of that.  I was attempting `\node[state](13)[above = 18.1mm] at (14){$S_1$};`.  Far less elegant.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I first thought of some shifting, but than I remembered this synthax. Luckily way easier than calculating each xshift.